# Perl, How to sort hash (of arrays) keys according to specific positions in arrays

Tags: perl

I have hash of array references. I want to sort hash keys according to those arrays' last element and if they are equal, then i want to sort them according to previous element and so on.

i have written a simple custom sort subroutine which sorts according to last element

```perl
    our %hash = (); #
    sub customsort($$)
    {   ${$hash{$_[0]}}[-1] <=> ${$hash{$_[1]}}[-1]    }
```

I know i need to pass another argument `$j` instead of predefined `-1` for fixed last element. Then i will set up a loop inside subroutine with some checks, etc. However i couldn't figure out how to pass it while using the subroutine in actual part of code

```
    foreach my $key (sort customsort keys (%hash)  ) {..}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %hash = (
  foo  => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
  bar  => [ 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 ],
  baz  => [ 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ],
  baz2 => [ 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ],
);

sub customsort {
  my $res;
  my $index = -1;

  while (1) {
    return 0 if ($#{$hash{$a}} + $index < 0) || ($#{$hash{$b}} + $index < 0);
    $res = ${$hash{$a}}[$index] <=> ${$hash{$b}}[$index];
    return $res if $res;
    $index--;
  }
} 

my @sorted = sort customsort keys %hash;
say $_ for @sorted;
```

I'm using `$a` and `$b` instead of the `($$)` prototype because Perl prototypes are generally best avoided, but also note that, according to [`perldoc sort`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html), using the prototype is slower.  So just embrace the magic of `$a` and `$b`.

The `return 0 if...` line is to prevent warnings if you have arrays of different lengths (`bar`) that have to look back beyond the beginning of a shorter array, and to prevent infinite loops if you have identical arrays (`baz` and `baz2`).

Comment: You put index inside subroutine without passing a parameter, that is nice, i didn't think that. I genuinely thank you.

Comment: 1) Re "*Perl prototypes are generally best avoided*", Maybe, but not here. Using prototypes is actually better for sort compare functions (since it allows them to be used by a `sort` in a different package). But yeah, it does slow down the sorting (because it's gotta pass arguments).

Comment: 2) `${$hash{$a}}[$index]` is a weird way of writing `$hash{$a}[$index]` (which is short for `$hash{$a}->[$index]`).

Comment: 3) A tiny bit faster: `my $aa = $hash{$a}; my $ab = $hash{$b}; my $last = @$aa < @$ab ? @$aa : @$ab;
    for my $i (1..$last) {
      my $res = $aa->[-$i] <=> $ab->[-$i];
      return $res if $res;
    }
    return 0;`

Comment: 4) Are you sure you should return 0 for arrays of different lengths? That doesn't sound right. Even if it doesn't matter, it's generally better to provide a consistent result. To place the shortest first, replace `return 0` with `return @${hash{$a}} <=> @${hash{$b}}` (or `return @$aa <=> @$bb` in mine). Sorting by key (`return $a cmp $b`) might also be desirable.